# Vue3 - how to get version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

in Vue2 I had:

```
console.log(Vue.version);
```

How do I get the version now in Vue 3?
Do I get it somehow out from the context?

Comment: Or `import { version } from 'vue'` if you use ESM builds.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work.

See example:

```js
console.log(Vue.version)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

The issue may be that you are calling a different vue bundle, try using/importing `vue.global`.